# Windows7: getaddrinfo returning "No such host is known" for [::1]

Tags: c++, windows-7-x64, ipv6, getaddrinfo, activemq-cpp

I'm working on modifications to my code to support dual stack environments on Windows 7 et. al.  The code uses ActiveMQ-CPP (3.8.4).  I've set this up to use a connection to the broker on URI "tcp://[::1]:61616".  I've already found I need to compile APR with APR_HAVE_IPV6.

Now the issue.  When APR's call_resolver() method calls getaddrinfo() with the hostname "[::1]", it returns "No such host is known" (code 11001).

I can ping [::1] without an issue.  I've tried uncommenting the ::1 entry in hostnames.  I've added the Internet Protocol Version 6 checkbox on my interfaces.

Any ideas what I'm missing?